# How to calculate mean and variance in the Weyl group $A_n$?

Tags: variance, means, weyl-group

Let the generation function for $A_n$ is the polynomial $\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac {(1-x^{k+1})} {(1-x)}$ as defined in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A161437).

For eg. for $n=5$ we have numbers:
$1, 5, 14, 29, 49, 71, 90, 101, 101, 90, 71, 49, 29, 14, 5, 1$, etc for other $n$.

I wonder how to calculate the mean and the variance of such a distribution for any $n$?
Actually I am looking for a clear explanation how to derive the final result. Any help are highly welcomed.

Comment: The probability of an element is number of occurrences in the sequence over length of the sequence?

Comment: @Jakobian I'm not sure. I just come accros on the sequence https://oeis.org/A161437

Comment: I mean, how is the probability defined. For example here probability of $1$ is $\frac{2}{16} = \frac{1}{8}$ because there's $2$ one's and $16$ numbers in the sequence?

Comment: @Jakobian Well, right. However, how to derive the mean and var generally? I mean I know how to calculate for a sample data set.

Comment: It's simple to calculate mean, but I am afraid variance might be problematic here.

Comment: Fine, could you add your way to calculate the mean please? Just to keep it here for a while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96221/discussion-between-mikhail-gaichenkov-and-jakobian).